# Play around with wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading

The following is an a self-tutored attempt to take a leap into understanding simple usage of `wait()` and `notify()` methods.

The code is responsible for scanning a directory structure with each directory being scanned by a new thread, for the files present in it. All results to get accumulated in a data collection and displayed at the end. The problem is to detect the end, since this is a chain reaction type.

```
class MyThreadA implements Runnable {

    private String path;
    private static List<String> FILE_LIST;
    private static AtomicInteger ATOMIC_COUNTER;

    static {
        ATOMIC_COUNTER = new AtomicInteger(0);
        FILE_LIST = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public MyThreadA(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int begin = ATOMIC_COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
            File filePath = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = filePath.listFiles();
            synchronized (System.out) {
                for (File temp : listOfFiles) {
                    if (temp.isFile()) {
                        FILE_LIST.add(temp.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(new MyThreadA(temp.getPath()));
                        t.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            MyThreadA.decrementCounter();
            //if(begin == 0)
                try {
                    synchronized (FILE_LIST) {
                        FILE_LIST.wait();
                    }
                    printList();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void decrementCounter() {
        if (ATOMIC_COUNTER.decrementAndGet() == 0)
            synchronized(FILE_LIST){
                FILE_LIST.notifyAll();
            }
    }

    private static void printList(){
        for(String temp:FILE_LIST){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see, all such spawned threads will wait to be notified. I can minimize this by letting the 1st thread only to wait, but that introduces one more critical section. I am looking for if there can be a better solution to this using `wait()` and `notify()` constructs only, with minimal concurrency tools.

I understand that there are better tools for solving this, but this is solely for learning purpose.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3):

There is a race condition in your code. When you call `t.start()` the thread doesn't start immediately which means that it's possible to have a thread waiting to execute but the current thread can call `notifyall` before the new thread has a chance to increment the counter. This can be fixed by doing the increment in the constructor instead of in run.

On another note, `FILE_LIST.add` is not safe to call from multiple threads. All the rest around that is safe. So, the for loop can be reduced to:

```
for (File temp : listOfFiles) {
    if (temp.isFile()) {
        synchronized (FILE_LIST) {
            FILE_LIST.add(temp.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else if (temp.isDirectory()) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyThreadA(temp.getPath()));
        t.start();
    }
}
```

When waiting on an object there is the (documented) possibility of a spurious wakeup, which means that the thread woke up without anyone calling `notify`.

The way to deal with that is to wait in a loop:

```
synchronized (FILE_LIST) {
    while(ATOMIC_COUNTER.get() > 0)
        FILE_LIST.wait();
}
```

The condition is inside the synchronized to avoid a race condition (not the one detailed above though).

Comment: Agreed to all your points, but my dilemma is between,
 - adding a critical section to prevent every thread from waiting, or
 - lessen the critical section and let all thread wait to be notified

Comment: Executed the code with your suggested changes. But it runs significantly slower. I guess that a free gift from concurrent programs.

Comment: @soufrk yeah just adding threads will add significant overhead for the synchronization between al the threads. I didn't mention doing a threadpool because you wanted to stay with the basics.

Comment: Completely agreed with you. Can you take a look at the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code like

```
class MyThreadA implements Runnable {

    private String path;
    // private static List<String> FILE_LIST;
    /*
     * Choosing a simple concurrent collection over
     * traditional List.
     */
    private static Queue<String> FILE_LIST;
    private static AtomicInteger ATOMIC_COUNTER;

    static {
        ATOMIC_COUNTER = new AtomicInteger(0);
        // FILE_LIST = new LinkedList<>();
        /*
         * Initializing 
         */
        FILE_LIST = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
    }

    public MyThreadA(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int begin = ATOMIC_COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
            File filePath = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = filePath.listFiles();
            synchronized (System.out) {
                for (File temp : listOfFiles) {
                    if (temp.isFile()) {
                        FILE_LIST.add(temp.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(new MyThreadA(temp.getPath()));
                        t.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            MyThreadA.decrementCounter();
            // if(begin == 0)
            /*
             * Difficult to understand, but theoretically notify() might
             * get invoked before the following; or wait might be released
             * by JVM without your notice due to internal reasons. 
             */
            while (ATOMIC_COUNTER.get() > 0)
                try {
                    synchronized (FILE_LIST) {
                        FILE_LIST.wait();
                    }
                    // printList();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            printList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void decrementCounter() {
        if (ATOMIC_COUNTER.decrementAndGet() == 0)
            synchronized (FILE_LIST) {
                FILE_LIST.notifyAll();
            }
    }

    private static void printList() {
        for (String temp : FILE_LIST) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a significant performance degradation that can be observed. Secondly, I am still wondering if, making 100 threads wait, is better than asking them to execute one more critical section (check for 0 before increment and exit if not).